# How to create map for each line based on the column using scala?

Tags: scala

I need to create map for each line based on the column using scala, for example,

```
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
```

I want output as,

```
RDD[List(
  Map(
    '0 -> 'sunny,
    '1 -> 'hot,
    '2 -> 'high,
    '3 -> 'false,
    '4 -> 'no
  ),
  Map(
    '0 -> 'overcast,
    '1 -> 'hot,
    '2 -> 'high,
    '3 -> 'false,
    '4 -> 'yes
  ),
  Map(
    '0 -> 'rainy,
    '1 -> 'mild,
    '2 -> 'high,
    '3 -> 'false,
    '4 -> 'yes
  )
)]
```

Here we consider each column, column number be the keys and column values be the values in the key-value pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Plain Scala

```
val s = """sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
          |overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
          |rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes""".stripMargin


s.split("\n").map { line =>
  line.split(",").zipWithIndex.map{ case (word, idx) => idx -> word}.toMap
}.toList
```

---

```
yields:
List(Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> no), 
     Map(0 -> overcast, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> yes), 
     Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> mild, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> yes))
```

---

- [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) splits a text on seperator
- [zipWithIndex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@zipWithIndex:Seq[%28A,Int%29]) 'maps' a Seq to a Tuple of (value, index)

  'Seq('a', 'b').zipWithIndex' yields  'Seq[(Char, Int)] = List((a,0), (b,1))'

---

we can improve the function to:

```
s.split("\n").map { line =>
  line.split(",").zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
}.toList
```

- because the result from 'zipWithIndex' are Tuples, which have the function [swap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2@swap:%28T2,T1%29) so we don't need to swap the elements byself

---

#### For Spark

```
sc.textFile(<file-with-data>).map { line =>
  line.split(",").zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
}
```

*thanks @Paul*

Comment: And this should work fine on Spark, if you replace `s.split("\n")` with `sc.textFile(<file-with-data>)` and drop the `.toList`

Comment: thanks @Paul - i add your improvements (think i need to learn spark)

Comment: I don't really know Spark, but I learnt a bit just to answer another question on SO about it. There are quite a few rather basic questions being asked

Comment: @Paul, This is RDD[...], I Want List[Map[Int,String]] by reading a text file

Comment: The first part of this answer is plain Scala. Reading a text file is just Source.fromPath("myfile.txt").getLines(). See http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-open-read-files-scala-examples if you need more info.